# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS freeze when opening pdf in Mozilla

Tags: freeze, pdf, mozilla

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. No problem so far, but it has been a few day that my system freeze when I am scrolling down pdf files opened in Mozilla.

No commands are accepted, so I have to shut-down the machine and re-start.
Any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: I feel your pain.  If you find a fix, I hope you post it here.  I'll be disabling PDFs most likely, but so far my specific issue seems like it might be happening when the JS gets too complex.  (PDFs are opened by default via PDF.js)

Answer (score 1):

Don't open PDF in Mozilla. In Mozilla, go to *preferences - Applications - PDF* and switch action from "Preview in Mozilla" to some application - Evince or Adobe Reader or whatever it is now.

Comment: The default is Evince.